# How to make a function that can set a max size in stack?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack

I made a stack below.

Now I want to add a function or method that allows you to specify the maximum size of the stack.

What do I need to change or add?

```
class MyStack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.myList = []
        self.top = -1
        self.size = 0


    def isEmpty(self):
        if (self.size > 0):
            return False
        else:
            return True

    def push(self, item):
        self.myList.append(item)
        self.size = self.size + 1
        self.top = self.top + 1

    def pop(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            return None
        else:
            self.ret = self.myList.pop(self.top)
            self.size = self.top - 1
            self.top = self.top - 1
            return self.ret

    def peek(self):
        if self.isEmpty():
            return None
        else:
            return self.myList[self.top]
```

Comment: you already had the code for `isEmpty()`, just added similiar codes for max_size.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your init function to accommodate max size

```
def __init__(self,maxsize):
    self.myList = []
    self.top = -1
    self.size = 0
    #ADDED
    self.max_size=maxsize
```

Also modify your push function :

```
def push(self, item):
    #check if you are exceeding the limit
    if(len(self.myList)<self.max_size):
        self.myList.append(item)
        self.size = self.size + 1
        self.top = self.top + 1
    else:
        print("Stack full")
```

Now it can be seen that :

```
#Initialise with 3 as max size
new_stack=MyStack(3)

#push 3 elements
new_stack.push(1)
new_stack.push(2)
new_stack.push(3)
#check the top
print("Try to peek :",new_stack.peek())
#OUTPUT : 3

#Try to push another element
new_stack.push(4) #output : Stack full
#check top again
print("Try to peek :",new_stack.peek())
#OUTPUT : 3 (still old one)
```